# unable to Raise a "File Download" Dialog Box using python cgi script

Tags: python, cgi, download

In my pursuit to pop up a download box in the client window(for sqlite3.db file). 
I wrote this code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
# HTTP Header
print "Content-Type:application/octet-stream; name=\"sqlite3.db\"\r\n";
print "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"sqlite3.db\"\r\n\n";

# Actual File Content will go hear.
fo = open("sqlite3.db", "rb")

str = fo.read();
print str

# Close opend file
fo.close()
```

I am experiencing an error(copied from error logs) mentioning **"IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'sqlite3.db' "**

I have also pasted both the python.py and sqlite3.db in /var/www/cgi-bin/
and i have assigned 0755 chmod to both.

I have checked by configuration by printing Hello world script.

Any idea what what is my mistake? i am still confused where should i give the path to the downloadable file?

Comment: I assume you dont have a file named "sqlite3.db" located in the same directory as where the script is called from ... try printing `os.getcwd()`

Comment: It could be that the cgi script is executed in the servers directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTTP header terminate early. (`print` itself write newline)

```
print "Content-Type:application/octet-stream; name=\"sqlite3.db\"\r\n";
print "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"sqlite3.db\"\r\n\n";
```

Abobe lines should be:

```
print 'Content-Type:application/octet-stream; name="sqlite3.db'
print 'Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="sqlite3.db'
print
```